# Angular controller load()

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind, angular-controller

This is a trivia for many, but I never worked with angular before and  I need help to achieve a simple task, cause I'm stucked.

My ng-controller **processctrl** has a `load()` method declared.
My view has two calls to `ng-controller="processoctrl"`, causing `load()` method to run twice. **processctrl** also has a property **currentPhase** that starts null and `load()` set its value. I could just write `($scope.currentPhase || load())` to prevent double `load()`, but the bind to currentPhase occurs atop (in DOM) of the repeater.

I could place an object property into the $rootScope and update it from processoctrl.scope.load(), but it would turn into a madness.

I could simply $($(".headerCurrentPhase")[0]).html($scope.currentPhase) into my load() method, but it's insanity too.

I could rewrite `load()` to `getProcesses = function(){}` and `$rootScope.$emit('getProcesses',{})` elsewhere and into the controller `$rootScope.$on('getProcesses',getProcesses)` to prevent this double `load()`, but I think this is redundate, so how to simply call a controller function instead of load()? Or how to achieve this simple task? Use a directive?

*view:*

```
<div ng-include src="'includes/overview-header.html'"></div>
<div ng-include src="'includes/process-info.html'"></div>
```

excerpt of *includes/overview-header.html* :

```
<div class="col-md-12">
....
    <h4><strong>currentPhase</strong></h4>
    <p ng-controller="processoctrl">
       <span class="label label-primary headerCurrentPhase" ng-bind="currentPhase"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

excerpt of *includes/process-info.html* :

```
<tbody ng-controller="processctrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="Process in Processes|orderBy:'ID'">
        <td>{{Process.isCurrent}}</td>
        <td>{{Process.isCurrent}}</td>
        <td>{{Process.ID}}</td>
        <td>{{Process.Title}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

*processoctrl*

```
(function (app) {
   app.controller('processctrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, factorysvc) {
       $scope.Processes = [];
       $scope.currentPhase = null;
       load();

       //($scope.currentPhase || load())

       function load() {
            var promiseGet = factorysvc.getPsby($routeParams.itemId);

            promiseGet.then(function (data) {

                $scope.Processes  = data;

                $rootScope.root.empreendimento.currentPhase = $scope.currentPhase = data[0].currentPhase.Title;

            }, function (err) {
                $scope.Message = "Error " + err.status;
            });

    }

})}(angular.module('sgaapp')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, I didn't catch what are you want to do, but I want to take you few advise:

1. Your logic it's really complicated, you should re-think it, cause now it's sucks;
2. Includes in angular sucks too. Really. You shouldn't use it at all. How to avoid it? Well, there is two option.

   - First is to use client-side routing (for pages); Instead of using built-in routing, better to use [ui-router](https://angular-ui.github.io). You will be able to use nested states and routes;
   - Second is to use directives instead of includes. Really, just imagine - header or footer, both can be directives, which you just include in pages when it's needed.

What for me - I use first and second solution in same time.

3. You should avoid to put anything in `$rootScope`. Perhaps it's couldn't kill you, and from time to time it's the only solution, but, u know, it's a bad practice.
4. If you need to store data and share it between controllers, the better option is to us factories (or other services, but factories most universal).

Example:

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function () {
    return {
        myData: 'some default value',
        someCommonFuction: function (a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }
    };
});
```

As well as data-store, you can use factory as utility-class, with common functions

Comment: I decided to abstract the things up. We deploeyd today a baseController and a factory prototype acting like a model. Tomorrow we're going to abstract the service (got  many1-1 controller-service querying the same endpoints for ListItems ). Thank you for your reply, @Sergey. Do you think I'm routing a good route, I mean, any adivices are welcome.

Comment: @egidiocs You know, it's hard to advice anything, but you can take a look at my old repo, perhaps it helps you: https://github.com/se-panfilov/outstanding_test

Answer (score 1):

Is there any real need to have 2 includes?

If overview-header is shared across views, then we can have currentPhase at $rootScope level or having a parent level controller and have it.

If overview-header is only for this view, then we can combine both htmls into one and have processctrl at wrapped tag.

Comment: Thank you @Sagar, I route to this design.